# How to display contents of global variable in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, counter

I wrote this for a class:

```
<% if @course.comments.exists? %>
      <h2>Ratings</h2>
      <% $total = 0 %>
      <% @course.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <p>
          <strong>Commenter:</strong>
          <%= comment.commenter %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Score:</strong>
          <%= comment.score %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Comment:</strong>
          <%= comment.comment %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Words in Comment:</strong>
          <%= comment.comment.length %>
        </p>
        <% $total += 1%>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy Rating', [comment.course, comment],
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <h2>No ratings available</h2>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <strong>Total Comments</strong>
      <%= print $total %>
    </p>
```

I have tried puts and print but nothing is displayed on my screen. I need to have it count each iteration of the `<% @course.comments.each do |comment| %>` line. Ruby is not my forte and the teacher has not been clear on how to achieve this goal. I am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use globals, as the name implies, they are global, which means it could be updates by other requests/threads.

If you are trying to find the total count of comments for a given @course, you could just call @course.comments.count. That should give you the total you are looking for.

Comment: This was very helpful. The result I needed to display were outside the loop so I wasn’t sure if I needed to make it global. I been studying python in my other class and I’m a little bit confused as to where you need to use global variable.